# CREATE LOGIN check_expiration and check_policy

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Just to know If I understood this correctly, both **check_policy** and **check_expiration** are taken from the Windows settings?

[image]

If I ever change the **maximum password age**, that would represent the check_expiration by default? and "**password complexity requirements**" represent the check_policy?

```
CREATE LOGIN [Stackoverflow] WITH PASSWORD=N'azeqsd789' MUST_CHANGE, DEFAULT_DATABASE=[master], CHECK_EXPIRATION=ON, CHECK_POLICY=ON
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is yes and the BOL article is [CREATE LOGIN (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-login-transact-sql)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The check_policy and check_expiration are set when a login is created, for example: 
 CREATE LOGIN [yourlogin] WITH PASSWORD=N'somepassword' MUST_CHANGE, DEFAULT_DATABASE=[yourdb], CHECK_EXPIRATION=ON

for clarification; CHECK_EXPIRATION=ON means that the password, not the login, will expire and has to be changed regularly.

Comment: You read my question? I know what it means but from where the values are retrieved from? If Check_expiration is ON, the default  date/x days should be available somewhere so I'm asking If its what I posted or I'm wrong

Comment: it looks like the answer is yes they come from the windows environment:  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/security/password-policy

Comment: When you set up the login you have to choose the authentication mode. Either SQL or Windows. if you choose the SQL authentication mode, the expiration is based on the local computer policy. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/security/choose-an-authentication-mode